# Braintree "shopping cart"-like implementation in rails app / finding previous params[:id]?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, braintree

I'm trying to integrate Braintree into my rails app which already has a deposits controller, model, and view.  Right now basically you can specify an amount but I have its status set to "Pending".  I would like it so that the user can make such a deposit but then pay for it at any time using Braintree (ala shopping cart).  Would I have to create another controller and/or model to do this?  (For example all the Braintree examples I've seen want the payment immediately).

Specifically, I've been trying to just work with the 'deposits' I already have.  I put the form for the user's name, credit card info, etc. on the deposits "show" page and a confirm button.  This seems to work fine if all fields satisfy validation, however it doesn't when there is an error and renders the show page again.
In DepositsController.rb:

```
 def confirm
  @deposit = Deposit.find(params[:id])
  @result = Braintree::TransparentRedirect.confirm(request.query_string)
  if @result.success?
    render :action => "confirm"
  else
    render :action => "show"
   end
 end
```

The problem is that `:id` now is the Braintree transaction ID, rather than the deposits id (primary key).  So of course `Deposit.find(params[:id])` can't be found.
What is the best way to implement this?  Should I store the previous id somehow or get it another way?  Should I be using another controller?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is you should be using a Cart model, connected to this Deposit model from what i can gather here.  Based on other questions, however, that feeling could change.

So, solely based on what you wrote above:

If we follow a RESTful approach, you should be creating a `Deposit#new` for all new deposits.

In your `Deposit#create`, you would then put all of your logic into the `deposit.rb` model file.  this logic includes, going to Braintree and such.

You say you are working with the deposits you already have, in that case, they should be handled in the `Deposit#edit` method.

Further questions I would ask of you in this regard, are you using ActiveMerchant?  If not, why not?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I decided to just simplify things and have only one "pending" deposit possible so I could find it easily, plus it makes more sense (and I don't have to think about storing the ID I was worried about).  I also decided to use Paypal instead and am using ActiveMerchant with that. Thanks

Comment: cool. So i guess i kind of helped you with the answer. if only stackoverflow had a box where you could show that appreciation...